# extract value from XML NSString avoiding use of a parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have this string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <CITY>Jupiter</CITY>
    <STATE>FL</STATE>
    <ZIP>33477</ZIP>
    <AREA_CODE>561</AREA_CODE>
    <TIME_ZONE>E</TIME_ZONE>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I just want to grab the City from it, in this case: Jupiter

I do not want to use an XML parser - is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: If you want to extract a value from XML then you _do_ want to use an XML parser - that _is_ the simple way to do it.  There's all sorts of complexities that a proper parser will handle for you (e.g. `Köln` and `K&#xF6;ln` are exactly the same value in XML), why re-invent the wheel.

Comment: seems like a ton of extra code, complexity, and maybe even an extra parser library to extract a single value from a string like the answer below does.

Comment: I suppose you can get away with string manipulation if it's XML that you've generated yourself and you know the exact format and know that it won't ever use character references, a DTD, CDATA sections, etc.  But parsing XML properly [doesn't have to be complex](http://nfarina.com/post/2843708636/a-lightweight-xml-parser-for-ios).

Comment: thanks for that link, currently this is the only XML I have to worry about but that article I am sure will help me in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend looking into using an xml parser but here you go anyway:

```
NSArray *array = [yourXMLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"CITY"];
NSString *city = [[array objectAtIndex:1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"></"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString* str=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile: FILENAME encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    NSRange range1= [str rangeOfString: @"<CITY>"];
    NSRange range2= [str rangeOfString: @"</CITY>"];
    NSUInteger location= range1.location+range1.length;
    NSUInteger length= range2.location-range1.location-range1.length;
    NSString* substr= [str substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(location,length)];
    NSLog(@"%@",substr);
```